# Unauthorized when calling Google Admin SDK Directory API

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

I'm having trouble calling Googles new Directory API. I'm getting http forbidden "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" all the time.

I'm using oauth2 and a service account to access the directory api. The oauth ticket is requested for the following scopes:

```
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user" 
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.group"
"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.orgunit"
```

The service account is owner of the Api project and the Admin SDK service is enabled. If I don't provide a Principal in the oauth request I get an oauth token but the request to the admin api fails.

If I provide a principal in the request for the oauth ticket the ticket will not be granted even if the principal is an administrator.

Do I have to give the service account additional privilegies to make it work or is there something I have missed. The same service account works fine for the calendar API.

Comment: Have you added the client ID of the service account under Manage third party OAuth Access? (the step is captured here: https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account)

Comment: I am trying to achieve the said. Kindly provide more details on approach. [My problem is listed here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22172909/using-google-directory-api-to-fetch-all-users-in-a-domain) @Tor Jonsson

Answer (score 1):

Have you assigned the ServiceAccountUser when initializing the authentication? I was having the same error before I set it to a domain manager account.

[See this one.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033593/cant-list-users-with-google-directory-api-admin-sdk/17039543#17039543)

Comment: Thanks for your help! It turned out that the authentication request failed because I also requested the https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly scope. Which was pointless. When I removed that scope everything works fine.