# Google Apps Admin SDK Directory API 403 in PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-apps

I'm getting

```
 Error calling GET https://www.googleapis.com/admin/directory/v1/users/email@example.com.com: (403) Not Authorized to access this resource/api
```

when running

```
        $client = new Google_Client();
        $client->setClientId(GOOGLEAPPS_CLIENT_ID);
        $client->setApplicationName(SITE_NAME);
        $key = file_get_contents(APPLICATION_PATH . 'googleapps-privatekey.p12');
        $assertion = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
                    GOOGLEAPPS_EMAIL_ADDRESS, // the service account name
                    array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'), // see https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing
                    $key);
        $client->setAssertionCredentials($assertion);
        $service = new Google_DirectoryService($client);
        $user = $service->users->get('email@example.com');
```

I followed the instructions https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/prerequisites
and ticked Enable API Access. I used the Google APIs console https://code.google.com/apis/console to generate a Service Account key and got that working OK.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-api-php-client/LM-mwmuZe7I/IA_K5v1R1UMJ

I used the Google PHP library and followed the instructions https://code.google.com/p/google-api-php-client/wiki/OAuth2?hl=no#Service_Accounts to try and get service accounts working. Debugging into their code: I'm authorising fine and getting a fresh Access token as expected https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount.

I can't figure out why I'm getting the "Not Authorized to access this resource/api" message when everything I have read says I've switched it all on OK. Any ideas?

Comment: hey steve, did you get this working in PHP eventually?

Comment: no. i decided to wait until Google finish rolling out their console updates. Their documentation is all messed up: you go around in circles clicking a link to the current docs but ending up at the obsolete docs. I've seen three different user interfaces for the setup for service accounts. Figured I just have to wait until they get it sorted out.

Answer (score 4):

Just got it working. You need to include the user email of the admin so oAuth authorizes you for that user. Try

```
    $assertion = new Google_AssertionCredentials(
                GOOGLEAPPS_EMAIL_ADDRESS, // the service account name
                array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user'), // see https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/guides/authorizing
                $key,
                'notasecret',
                'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',
                'admin_user@email.com'
    );
```

Also after that you need to authorize the client_id for the scope you are requesting from Admin console->Security->Advanced Settings->Authentication->Manage OAuth Client access

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem.  I'm using the .NET libraries.  The `[DriveService][1]` example was missing a parameter when creating the provider: ServiceAccountUser, which appears to have to be the email address of an ADMIN.  I missed that it was an admin and was getting:

```
Not Authorized to access this resource/api [403]
```

as soon as I switched it to an admin account, it worked.  I'm afraid I don't speak PHP but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you get an error

```
Class 'Google_AssertionCredentials' not found
```

you are using the newer libraries, and `Google_AssertionCredentials` is now `Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials`.

See:
https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Auth/AssertionCredentials.php

Answer (score 0):

Did you grant the service account access to the given scopes within your Control Panel? See the [instructions in the Drive SDK](https://developers.google.com/drive/delegation#delegate_domain-wide_authority_to_your_service_account) and substitute in the Admin SDK scopes as needed.

Comment: Yes i did. Got tangled up a bit in the old admin console: it keeps linking to the old OAuth 1.0 documentation which is obsolete. Still don't have it working. Might have to wait until our console gets upgraded to the new version.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16774112/unauthorized-when-calling-goolge-admin-sdk-directory-api