# Google Directory API with PHP Client Library gives 403

Tags: google-api-php-client, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I have gone over several questions in regards to Directory API and PHP Client lib but none helped. The closest one was this one:
[Google Apps Admin SDK Directory API 403 in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19112058/google-apps-admin-sdk-directory-api-403-in-php)
However the problem still persists.

I cannot access the Directory API (Admin SDK) using the PHP client Library.

I CAN access the Email Settings API.

They are both related to the Admin SDK, so I do not understand why when I access the email settings API I get a token, but when I try to access the Directory API I get 403 "Requested client not authorized."

The code is

```
    $scopes = array('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user',
'https://apps-apis.google.com/a/feeds/emailsettings/2.0/');
    $auth = new Google_Auth_AssertionCredentials(G_CLIENT_EMAIL, $scopes,file_get_contents (G_CLIENT_KEY_PATH),
                    'notasecret',
                    'http://oauth.net/grant_type/jwt/1.0/bearer',
                    'my.superadmin@account.com', false
        );
```

What am I missing?

ALSO: How the heck do you use the logging/debugging class in PHP Client lib?
I see the abstract class but could not figure out how to use it. In the end I just placed my own print statements in Curl.php to inspect what was going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error, initially I thought of deleting the question out of shame, but it might help someone else save a few hours.

Basically in the project console, there are 2 client IDs, a native App ID and a service account ID.

When I extended the projects scope, I used the wrong client ID in the domain control panel.  Even though it was something I checked over and over again, it was not something I saw until I was preparing a document for Google Support. Only when I copied and pasted what I placed in the control panel bellow what I saw in the project console, I saw that only the first set of digits matched.

wooops.